# What is the difference between targeting platform "Win32" and targeting platform "x86" and why aren't they compatible?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, winrt-component

I'm building a new solution that has some code already built in. The first project is a Win32 console app and the second is a Windows Runtime Component. I can't make a reference from the win32 project to the WinRT component because they target different platforms. I've tried to create a new platform option but with no success.
I read that `Win32` can target chipsets that `x86` cannot. But with the minimal messing around, I can't seem to get it to match up. I will only run this solution for `windows 10 (16299)` and later if that matters.

What's the difference and what's the correct way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this Microsoft's doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-configure-projects-to-target-platforms?view=vs-2019#target-platforms-with-the-configuration-manager)?

Comment: I'm currently working through this page. Thanks for the link. I see that it says, "The Win32 platform name is used for C++ projects, and it means x86.", but I still have the same error. I thought It might've been an ambiguous term for `<targetplatform>` in the project file, but both the project and winrt component are targeting the same windows 10 version.

Comment: I've tried the instructions on the page but still haven't gotten the reference to work with the manager dialog. I did include a reference to the `.winmd` file that the winrt component project outputs, though I read somewhere that it's not suggested due to compiler issues since the component is a work in progress. However I have a different problem now related to `Unable to load DLL '__Internal': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)` which I'll make a different post for.